# Powershell - windows hard-disk health status is giving inconsistent results

Tags: windows, powershell

I am using the below PowerShell script to fetch hard-disk health status of windows machine:
`Get-PhysicalDisk | Select HealthStatus`

Issue: For few of the machines the hard-disk health status is frequently changing from warning to healthy and vice-versa.

I wanted to understand why the same PowerShell script is giving varied results.
If anyone has any idea on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: That's common. The script is only retrieving what the computer is telling you. Whether it's in a good state, or not. Maybe run a system file checker against it

Comment: thank you @AbrahamZinala.What do you mean by run a system file checker? I just want to know the hard-disk health status of machine. Is there any other way we get constant value always?

Comment: `sfc.exe`. The command isn't the issue here, it's the system(s) hdd. You can compare it using other cmdlets like `Get-Disk`, or a `Get-CimInstance` cmdlet. Not sure if they all just query CIM tho. I would try asking on SuperUser for further help

Comment: Try chkdsk instead! Sorry, just woke up.

Comment: no problem @AbrahamZinala.I tried chkdsk its not giving me the result what I am looking for. And I tried Get-Disk cmd it gives me hard-disk health status, but still as you said result may vary. And if you have asked on superuser,could you please add link for same where I can see updates.

Comment: I believe the `HealthStatus` property uses SMART values to determine the status, at least in part. Most manufacturers have their own software and smart data params for checking health, but you could also try one of these to get more information (if your hdds support it): `Get-PhysicalDisk|Get-StorageReliabilityCounter` or `Get-CimInstance MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus -Namespace root\wmi`

Comment: Thank you @Cpt.Whale.Will check on these scripts

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I tried `Get-CimInstance MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus -Namespace root\wmi` it as one of the "PredictFailure" field. Issue is its not working on some of the makes/machines of laptop(like lenovo).Is there any other way/script which supports on all makes/machines to get the result.

Comment: Anyone who can help me on this issue would be helpful, looking for alternate query to fetch HardDisk Status or PredictFailure status of system/machine which works on all types of laptop manufacturers.